# Conditions for unique, infinite, and no solutions of optimization problem

Tags: optimization

I have attached the question I am referring to. I assume for the uniqueness one, we can say that the condition is that it has to be a convex function with a global minima. But that does not seem right. And I'm not sure at all about the infinite and no solutions.

Additionally, for part (b) am I to just write the derivative of the function equal to 0?

[image: Question]

Comment: Where is the question 'attached'?

Comment: Apologies. It is added.

Comment: Hints: What happens if $a$ is positive, negative or zero? If $a$ is zero, what happens if $b$ is positive, negative or zero.  (Bonus hint: $c$ does not affect the answers)

Comment: Thank you for that. I wasn't exactly sure what KIND of conditions they were asking for. This confirms it. Can you also take a look at what I asked about the part (b) please?

Answer (score 0):

If `f''(x) > 0` then the function is concave up(for all `x`). So it will have minimum. Then it has unique solution if it holds for all value of `x`.

Now infinitely many solution: In case a = 0 then then `f = bx+c`. Differentiating it we get `f'(x)=b`. So it cant be `0` anywhere. So that means it doesn't have a global max or min. This is the case of `no solution`.

What happens if `b=0` then we get `f = c`. A plane. Now if we differentiate it we have `0` but `f''(x) = 0` everywhere. Which means it is an inflection point. But if we look aside in the terrain it is always the same. So it has infinitely many minimas.

Comment: @Henry.: Can you check the answer reasoning?